# How to code a nested case in shell script with arguments given in shell prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, case, sh

I'm having this error when trying to execute this shell script.

I'm new to scripting so this may be a basic error, but I'm not managing to solve it..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpo6R.jpg

Script Code:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "--------- Begin Script ---------"
echo "Begin"

echo "Which module you would like to export? 
      1 - P
      2 - C
      3 - M
      4 - L"

select answer1 in "1" "2" "3" "4"; do
    case $answer1 in
        1 ) echo ""
            echo "-------------------------------------"

                select answer2 in "a" "b" "c"; do
                    case $answer2 in
                        a) echo $answer2;
                            break;;

                        b) echo $answer2;
                            break;;

                        c) echo $answer2;
                            break;;
                    esac
                done
            break;;

        2 ) echo ""
            echo "-------------------------------------"

                select answer2 in "a" "b" "c"; do
                    case $answer2 in
                        a ) echo $answer2
                            break;;

                        b) echo $answer2
                            break;;

                        c) echo $answer2
                            break;;
                    esac
                done
            break;;

        3 ) echo ""
            echo "-------------------------------------"

                select answer2 in "a" "b" "c"; do
                    case $answer2 in
                        a ) echo $answer2
                            break;;

                        b) echo $answer2
                            break;;

                        c) echo $answer2
                            break;;
                    esac
                done
            break;;

        4 ) echo ""
            echo "-------------------------------------"

                select answer2 in "a" "b" "c"; do
                    case $answer2 in
                        a ) echo $answer2
                            break;;

                        b) echo $answer2
                            break;;

                        c) echo $answer2
                            break;;
                    esac
                done
            break;;
    esac
done
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It runs perfectly on my machine. I think is a formatting prolem.
If you are using a windows editor or something odd to write the code then maybe is a strange symbol problem. Try to activate UNIX-like systems text format in your editor if it is the case. Or just type it with gedit.